# Batch request and process in parallel in Node with async iterators

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, async-await

I have a small function that gets sent log to it. In the function, I am trying to send the to AWS Cloudwatch however I have a few issues. Once one log has been sent I can not send another one until the first one has finished as I need the next sequenceToken so the next log knows where to add itself. I know that async iterators are the key here but not sure how to implement them in my code. Here is my current code which fails after the first log is sent:

```js
const build = require('pino-abstract-stream');

const stream = async (options) => {
    // Creates the AWS connection
    const client = await createClient();
 
    // Gets the first token
    let sequenceToken = await getInitSequenceToken(client);

    return build(function (source) {
        source.on("data", async function (obj) {
            // Every time the log is sent to my worker thread it prints out here. Obj contains the info from the log
            const command = new PutLogEventsCommand({
                logGroupName: "api",
                logStreamName: `executive-${Config.env}-${Config.location}`,
                logEvents: [
                    {
                        message: obj.msg,
                        timestamp: obj.time,
                    },
                ],
                sequenceToken,
            });

            // Here I am sending the log to Clouwatch 
            const response = await client.send(command);
        
            // Here I was updating the token but this fails as the next log is already sending 
            sequenceToken = response.nextSequenceToken;
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: What is `source`, a websocket ?

Comment: Logs from pino using custom transport: https://github.com/pinojs/pino-abstract-transport

Comment: use the first example from that link the one with `for await`, that is the "sync" version.

Comment: I know I can use the first example and send one requests at time but surely is better to batch them and that is where I am falling over as really unsure how to do that.

Comment: @AlexanderKaran, You cannot batch them if I understand correctly because you need to wait for the previous one to finish and get the next token.

Comment: You can store the `response` in an outside variable(array), then once the stream close ( `source.on('end')` ), you'll loop with a [reduce over the client.send](https://css-tricks.com/why-using-reduce-to-sequentially-resolve-promises-works/)

Comment: Surely though we can wait for a few logs to come through, then send one request. Log events can take an array. Once we have sent one request we start collecting logs then send another request.

Comment: Or maybe I’m just having a fever dream cus I have been looking at code for to long today and I’m over thinking ha!

Comment: @AlexanderKaran, I got your point. Anyway, you should quote the people in your comment. otherwise, they may not see it.

Comment: Oversight here on my part. The stream does not end unless the server shuts down. There is data being sent to the stream on and off the whole time the server is live

Answer (score 2):

You can wait for the stream(`source`) to finish, and store all objects into an array then send them with one request - seeing that `logEvents` accepts an array with multiple objects - that would probably be the better solution since you have timestamps on objects and you'll have them all grouped under one `sequenceToken`:

```
const build = require('pino-abstract-stream');

const stream = async(options) => {
  // Creates the AWS connection
  const client = await createClient();

  // Gets the first token
  let sequenceToken = await getInitSequenceToken(client);
  let storeStreamObjects = [];
    
  return build(function(source) {
    source.on("data", async function(obj) {
      storeStreamObjects.push({
        message: obj.msg,
        timestamp: obj.time,
      });
    });
    source.on("close", async () => {

      const command = new PutLogEventsCommand({
        logGroupName: "api",
        logStreamName: `executive-${Config.env}-${Config.location}`,
        logEvents: storeStreamObjects, // all objects are here
        sequenceToken,
      });

      return await client.send(command);

    })
  });
};
```

Comment: Can not believe I did not see this solution, typical over thinking a problem. Thanks

Comment: Oversight here on my part, the stream does not end unless the server shuts down. There is data being sent to the stream on and off the whole time the server is live

Comment: I've changed the finish event from `end` to `close` since they say it's a [split2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/split2) instance.

Answer (score 1):

If the logs can be sent later to the cloud, you may do something like this below.

```js
const build = require("pino-abstract-stream");

const stream = async options => {
  // Creates the AWS connection
  const client = await createClient();

  // Gets the first token
  let sequenceToken = await getInitSequenceToken(client);

  const steamData = [];

  return build(function (source) {
    source.on("data", async function (obj) {
      steamData.push(obj);
    });

    source.on("end", async function () {
      // Every time the log is sent to my worker thread it prints out here. Obj contains the info from the log
      for (const data of steamData) {
        const command = new PutLogEventsCommand({
          logGroupName: "api",
          logStreamName: `executive-${Config.env}-${Config.location}`,
          logEvents: [
            {
              message: data.msg,
              timestamp: data.time,
            },
          ],
          sequenceToken,
        });

        // Here I am sending the log to Clouwatch
        const response = await client.send(command);

        sequenceToken = response.nextSequenceToken;
      }
    });
  });
};
```